# Aptana Code Assist

Tags: ruby, aptana3, content-assist

I'm new to Ruby language(v1.9.3) and Aptana. I'm having problems with Aptana(3.2.2 version) code assist. The problem is that it is not showing up any of the core/ library methods for any data types. For example if I type:

```
s= String.new("hello")
#Expecting the IDE to show up capitalize method when I type 'c' after string
s.c
---
#Expecting the IDE to show up capitalize method when I type 'c' after string
"hello".c
---
s="hello"
#Expecting the IDE to show up capitalize method when I type 'c' after string
s.c
```

The code assist pops up after I type "." and disappears after typing the letter 'c'. What I'm expecting here is the IDE to show up capitalize method in String. However, it is not showing up capitalize() or any other string methods. However if I type a '.' after a string, it detects it as a string correctly, but the code assist shows other methods such as toutf16(),block_scanf() .. etc and not the library methods which is what I wanted.

I have tried changing the file associations(by making  Aptana Source Editor default in Window >> Preferences >> Editors >> File Associations >> *.rb ). The IDE code assist shows the class methods I have implemented, but not any of the library methods. It will be very helpful if it can offer me the library methods as given in Ruby documentation.

Comment: Don't expect very good autocomplete and autoassist with any IDE for a dynamic language. Even RubyMine, a paid IDE made specially for Ruby, doesn't have that great support. Don't expect much out of an IDE that specializes in JavaScript and HTML. Get used to typing. It's the way of the UNIX languages. if you want autocomplete, go to Java and C#.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a text editor like textmate, vim or emacs and use the ruby docs in a browser window or in terminal. IDEs don't really work with Ruby and when you're learning Ruby you'll learn with blogs etc. None of these refer to IDEs and you will be constantly trying to translate that into your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **real autocompletion**, the best way (at least for me) is to use **Interactive Ruby Shell** like **IRB**, or it's replacement. One which I like the most is [PRY](http://pryrepl.org/). Installation is really trivial:

```
$ gem install pry
$ pry
```

In the console just use [TAB] key to autocomplete and it shows you all the possibilities.
I can also recommend you to watch [Pry Screencast video](https://vimeo.com/26391171) by Joshua Cheek, where he explains most important features of the **Pry**.